# Firebase leitura de caminhos (true)

Tags: firebase

Tenho uma dúvida referente a leitura no Firebase em caminhos `true`. Meu banco está estruturado desta forma:

```
"servicos"{
    "servico1" : {
             "nome" : "servico1",
             "desc" : "este é  o servico1"
     },
    "servico2" : {
             "nome" : "servico2",
             "desc" : "este é  o servico2"
    }
},

"users":{
    "user1":{
          "nome" : "usuario1",
    },
    "user2":{
          "nome" : "usuario2",
          "tabelas" : {
               "servico1" : true
          }
    }
}
```

Ao fazer uma consulta ao `user2` eu recebo:

> ```
> key = user2, values = {nome = usuario2, servico1 = true}
> ```

Como eu faço para receber os dados que estão dentro de `servico1` ao realizar esta consulta ao `user2`?

Tipo ao consultar `user1` queria receber o nome do `servico2` e a `desc` do `servico2`.

Comment: Você deve realizar uma nova consulta no nó serviços buscando a chave servico1. O firebase não retorna esses dados automaticamente, o uso da forma "key": true serve para evitar a duplicação de código.

Comment: Evite ficar criando perguntas idênticas. Você fez exatamente a mesma pergunta naquela que indicaram duplicata